# PHP cURL setup to send to remote host

Tags: php, forms, curl

I have a few elementary questions about cURL that I can't find answered in the cURL docs (probably because they are obvious to everyone else...). I have a file type input in a form that needs to send that file to a remote server. Does the cURL code go on the page with the form, or is the cURL on the page that the form sends you to, then it gets sent to the remote server?

Here is the form html:

```
<form action="send.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="file">Filename:</label>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" /> 
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

The cURL php I have so far which I don't even know if it's correct for what I'm trying to do, or if this goes on the same page or the send.php file the form goes to:

```
$ch = curl_init("http://remoteServer/upload_file.php"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CUROPT_POSTFIELDS, array('fileupload' => '@'.$_FILES['theFile']      ['tmp_name'])); 
echo curl_exec($ch);`
```

And on the remote server I have this file to receive it:

```
$folder = "files/";
$path = $folder . basename( $_FILES['file']['name']); 
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $path)) {
    echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['file']['name']). " has been uploaded";
} else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
```

Is this even remotely close?

Comment: You don't need to use cURL for receiving a file upload from a browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need curl to upload a file from a browser, you can submit the form directly to the remote server to upload - just make sure the form submits to whatever file has that third block of code

Comment: I tried that and was getting the error message every time. I posted a question on here about it and everyone said to use cURL or ftp. If I was to cut out cURL, how does the file actually get to the remote server?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
$curlPost = array('fileupload' => '@'.$_FILES['theFile'] ['tmp_name']);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://remoteServer/upload_file.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curlPost);
$data = curl_exec();
curl_close($ch);
```

**Another Example**

**How to upload image file to remote server with PHP cURL**

http://www.maheshchari.com/upload-image-file-to-remote-server-with-php-curl/

Comment: I was looking at the link, but I still am not sure where the cURL code goes. Looking at the links example I got the impression it goes on the remote server, is that correct?